# C# Using Emgu to crop an image by pixel color

Tags: c#, image-processing, crop, emgucv

Hey i was wondering if anyone had any insight on how to crop an image by pixel color using the Emgu Wrapper.

I have it already turn the image grayscale for processing and all the image that i don't need is black. Is there any way to crop these pixels out? Now I'm not talking about making them transparent, i physically want to make the output image smaller.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really simple... all you have to do is set your input image ROI property on the non black pixels using a rectangle, then you create the destination image with image equals to ROI size and use Copy() method on your input image choosing as destination your dest image.
HTH, Luca

Comment: Wish you could 'say' that in example codes... Thanks